# android background apps can receive fcm only after triggerred by firebase console

Tags: java, android, firebase, background, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to push notification when app is swipe out from recent task
First try I push notification using postman but notification not show.
second try I push notification using firebase console, and notification is show, then I try push using postman and it working.
my question why if I only push using postman it's not working, but if I triggered using firebase console then use postman it's can work? how to push without triggered from firebase console?

this my android code

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {
    super.onNewToken(token);
    Log.d("TAG", "New token: " + token);
    storeRegIdInPref(token);
}

private void storeRegIdInPref(String token) {
    SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("FCMID", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("regId", token);
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    if (remoteMessage.getData()!= null)
        try {
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();

            PushNotificationModel pushNotificationModel = PushNotificationModel.fromMap(data);
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);

            resultIntent.putExtra("Title", pushNotificationModel.title);
            resultIntent.putExtra("Message", pushNotificationModel.message);
            resultIntent.putExtra("NotifId", 2020090001);

            showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), pushNotificationModel.title, pushNotificationModel.message,  "2020-09-29 17:45:22", resultIntent, 2020090001);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     /*if (remoteMessage == null)
        return;

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0)
    {
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    else if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() , remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    }*/
}
private void handleNotification(String message , String Title) {
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
    showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), Title, message, "" , resultIntent,0);
}

private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {
    try {
        String title = json.getString("title");
        String message = json.getString("message");
        String timestamp = json.getString("timestamp");
        String notifid = json.getString("notifid");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(notifid);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra("Title", title);
        resultIntent.putExtra("Message", message);
        resultIntent.putExtra("NotifId", notifid);

        showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent, id);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent , int notifid) {
    /*PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    try {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 60002, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        pendingIntent = null;
    }
    Bitmap Images;
    String channelId = "channel-01";
    String channelName = "Channel Name";
    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    *//*NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilderWithImage = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(Images).setSummaryText(message))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);*//*


    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilderWithText = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.logo))
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

    if (pendingIntent != null) {
        notificationBuilderWithText.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        *//*if(Images != null){
            notificationBuilderWithImage.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        } else {
            notificationBuilderWithText.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        }*//*
    }

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    *//*if(Images != null){
        notificationManager.notify(0 *//**//* ID of notification *//**//*, notificationBuilderWithImage.build());
    } else {
        notificationManager.notify(0 *//**//* ID of notification *//**//*, notificationBuilderWithText.build());
    }*//*
    notificationManager.notify(0 *//* ID of notification *//*, notificationBuilderWithText.build());*/


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    int notificationId = notifid;
    String channelId = "channel-01";
    String channelName = "Channel Name";
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                channelId, channelName, importance);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(message));

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

and this my postman code

```
{
"data": {
    "message": "\"Henlo6\"",
    "notifid": 2020090001,
    "timestamp": "\"2020-09-29 17:45:22\"",
    "title": "\"Hai\"",
    "priority":"HIGH"
},
"time_to_live": 86400,
"to": "token"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have exited the app, so the messaging service was died. If you want to receive notifications without the app being running, You should add "notification" part of the payload when using postman.

```
{
    "notification": {
        "title":"",
        "body":""
    },
    "data": {
        "message": "\"Henlo6\"",
        "notifid": 2020090001,
        "timestamp": "\"2020-09-29 17:45:22\"",
        "title": "\"Hai\"",
        "priority":"HIGH"
    },
    "time_to_live": 86400,
    "to": "token"
}
```

see: [Receive messages in an Android app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Comment: yeah I already try that but in android 10 is still not working